# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

Tags: linux, fedora

Where can I find this library and how to install it?

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's for OpenSSL: you probably want a package named openssl-devel on Fedora (openssl-dev on Debian).

Comment: Thanks ! To install it on Fedora I used: "yum -y install openssl-devel"